# What does the expression {headers : headers} evaluate to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading through a [tut-spring-security-and-angular-js Tutorial](https://github.com/oleersoy/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/single/README.adoc) and it contains the following expression line:

```
$http.get('user', {headers : headers}).then(function(response)
```

What does the `{headers : headers}` expression evaluate to?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an object literal with one propetry `headers` equal to whateever is stored under variable named `headers`.

A little easier to understand example:

```
var someValue = "aaa";
var myObject = {
  someKey: someValue 
};

var headers = "abcdef";
var secondParameter = {
  headers: headers
};

$.get("...", secondParameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer @Crozin provided, the value of headers is defined in the documentation page just a couple lines up:

```
var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
        + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
    } : {};
```

This is saying that if the variable `credentials` is defined, `headers` will be an object containing the authorization data from the `credentials` variable. Otherwise, `headers` will be an empty object.